# Failed command: WRITE DMA EXT

Tags: hard-drive, sata

One day my PC did not boot up properly, just froze in the BIOS but after a few cycles it booted up extremely slowly. The drive's SMART diagnostics reported nothing unusual. Just all these DMA errors. I thought I solved it by replacing the drive, but now the second drive has gotten these same DMA errors. I also swapped the cable to see if it was the issue.

```
[  870.836058] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
[  870.836067] ata4.00: BMDMA stat 0x26
[  870.836073] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[  870.836083] ata4.00: cmd 35/00:48:30:19:28/00:01:01:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 167936 out
                        res 51/84:08:70:1a:28/84:00:01:00:00/e0 Emask 0x30 (host bus error)
[  870.836088] ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  870.836092] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
```

What should I do or check more? Is my motherboard's controller dying or killing the drives (UPDATE: Nope, both disks work fine no DMA errors on a different motherboard. The controller also wiped the first drive's partition table)? The previous week the old power supply went out too, could these things be related?

Comment: The above error msg also occurs when attempting new installation of 16.04 server or 16.04 desktop This would imply a fault with the installation programs and not the installation or update machine it has just started to occur about 2months ago from 11 - Oct - 16 I have sent numerous fault msgs so the correction I believe should be done in the installation files this appears to be a common fault. As well as ext not read it faults on interupt 16 also

Comment: Well, for me the cause was the motherboard, I'd recommend you try the drive in another PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already replaced the drive and cable, then there is only one thing left it could be ( unless you replaced the cable with another bad one ): the controller.  Do you happen to have a first generation sandybridge Intel P67 chipset?  If so, these were known to have SATA controller failures like this and were recalled a few years ago to fix the issue.

Comment: Nope, no sandy bridge. But damn, that means I need a replacement. :/

Comment: I replaced the motherboard and it seems to be okay now.